# Hide Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request

When I add a tag to my ignored tags, questions with that tag do not disappear, they are just greyed out, and they continue to clutter my feed. I have searched for an option to change this, but have not found one.

Is there a way to do this?

If not, I understand other stackexchanges have this option. Could it be added to Ethereum stackexchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the right side panel when ignoring a tag it gives the two options

[image]